# Python: How do I prevent long variable names in scope

Tags: python, variables, scope

I have stuff like:
self.megacity.resourceloader.sound.mcintro.play()

Is there any elegant way to prevent such long stuff like this?
Some sort of structural change, perhaps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = self.megacity.resourceloader.sound.mcintro
x.play()
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) to help you find better ways to loosen coupling between components in your program:

> When applied to object-oriented programs, the Law of Demeter can be
>   more precisely called the “Law of Demeter for Functions/Methods”
>   (LoD-F). In this case, an object A can request a service (call a
>   method) of an object instance B, but object A cannot "reach through"
>   object B to access yet another object, C, to request its services.
>   Doing so would mean that object A implicitly requires greater
>   knowledge of object B's internal structure. Instead, B's interface
>   should be modified if necessary so it can directly serve object A's
>   request, propagating it to any relevant subcomponents. Alternatively,
>   A might have a direct reference to object C and make the request
>   directly to that. If the law is followed, only object B knows its own
>   internal structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), eg:

```
class SoundPlayer:
    def play_megacity(self):
        return self.megacity.resourceloader.sound.mcintro.play()
```